# Please welcome your new Moderators!

Tags: discussion, moderation

Moderators, check your email. I am pleased to announce that these members have generously stepped up to volunteer their time to help us assure that the community issues are properly addressed.

[image]

[image]

[image]

*Congratulations on your appointment!*

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community in both community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as Moderators. You can read about the program here:

[**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)

These members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

### Did I overlook anyone?

**Almost certainly**. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why we will hold elections when the community is large enough to support them.

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the opportunity! Will give it my best!

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible nominate [confused00](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/users/961/confused00) as a moderator?  If not, is there a protocol for an election process?

Comment: I support this nomination. He is a very active and reviewing member of this community.

Comment: It is evidently preferred that users self nominate themselves (1).   There does not seem to be an official template for elections ((2) is probably a good start). 

It may be too early according to one post which recommends elections take place 6-9 months after the initial launch.

  (1)https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75382/how-can-you-nominate-someone-other-than-yourself-for-being-a-moderator
  (2)https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1212/community-moderator-election-format-and-design

Comment: Generally, we don't run elections until a site is active enough to have an election, meaning it "graduates". For most sites, this is not really time-based but more based on meeting the Area 51 goals, particularly the questions per day. For Beta sites, we usually appoint new moderators if the moderators feel that they can't manage the current work load or if one of the moderators steps down or disappears. In these cases, it's good to know who else we might turn to. That said, we've started running elections on some beta sites, but not on a schedule, based on need.

Comment: You can see more about testing beta elections here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections

Comment: Yeah I support this too and i support @Nat to have this right as well